# How to trigger page refresh to update value change in sibling components in UI

Tags: angular, refresh, parent-child, angular-ui, angular2-changedetection

I am facing issue when one sibling component changes value to be displayed in another sibling component. The value is being changed in script end, whereas the UI is not getting reflected of the change.

Comment: can you please add a stackblitz or some POC code for better explanation of the issue?

Comment: I want to understand how the changes in one component are being passed to another component e.g. via property or you are maintaining some global app state etc.

In either case, you might want to see and use [rxjs][1]. Using observable, you can achieve what you are looking for. 


  [1]: https://www.learnrxjs.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to communicate the component to component,

1. @Input and @output if components organised parent and child
2. Rxjs Subject , Behaviour subject for sibiling components, and individual path components
3. view child

In your case I think it good to use subject . Please find [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzesrn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
 maybe it will help to you

Thanks

Comment: Thank you @Soumya behaviour subject was useful... definitely solved the issue

Comment: If my answer is useful click uparrow and right tick

Answer (score -1):

What you need is `location.reload()` if you want to refresh the page. This line of code acts like pressing F5 in the browser so consider if is there any data or change you want to keep or you are fine with the complete page refresh.

Otherwise consider using a service as suggested in the other comment.